# How much HP does the Core have?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Heroes of the Storm, how much HP and maximum shield does the Core have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest answer I've been able to find was this bit from the [May 2015 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/19067455/heroes-closed-beta-patch-notes-may-12-2015-5-12-2015#Battlegrounds):

> Basic Training
>
> - Core Health reduced from 14,000 (+400 per level) to 11,000 (+300 per level)
> - Core Shields reduced from 7,000 (+200 per level) to 5,500 (+150 per level)

Which implies that the Core Health in other modes is 14,000 (+400 per level) and the shields are 7,000 (+200 per level).  This seems to roughly match with my experience, where a 1400 damage Orbital Strike from Nova can knock off ~10% of a core's health around level 20.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the latter values? I think 14,000 and 7,000 are the prior values.

Comment: The notes said the new values are only used for basic training so presumably QM/Versus use the 14000 and 7000.  On the other hand, 1000 damage at level 20 is doing about 7% of the core's health, so I'm not actually sure there's any scaling factor at all.  I'll continue to observe.